# Mordecai: Can't connect to Elasticsearch container running locally

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, elasticsearch, nlp

I have been working on an NLP project and would like to try out Mordecai as a geoparser. However, after quite a bit of effort in getting the module set up on an EC2 instance, I'm having some networking problems that prevent me from using it.

Specifically, when I start the Elasticsearch container and then try to initialize the geoparser, I get the following error:

```
2021-03-19 20:37:58.635480: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-19 20:37:58.661873: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-03-19 20:37:58.663206: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-03-19 20:37:58.664572: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (ip-172-31-79-96): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-03-19 20:37:58.668768: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-19 20:37:58.668930: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
GET http://localhost:9200/geonames/_count [status:N/A request:0.002s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I suspect that this error has something to do with my networking setup, but I really have no idea on how to resolve it or where to start.

For reference, the set of commands that got me to this point are:

```
sudo zypper --non-interactive install python3-pip # install pip3 

pip3 install mordecai # install mordecai 

python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg # install the missing spacy model 

pip3 install -I h5py==2.10.0 # install the keras-compatible h5py version

sudo systemctl start docker # start docker  

sudo docker pull elasticsearch:5.5.2 # pull the elasticsearch image 

wget https://andrewhalterman.com/files/geonames_index.tar.gz --output-file=wget_log.txt # Get the geoparser files 

tar -xzf geonames_index.tar.gz # Extract the tarball 

docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -v $(pwd)/geonames_index/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data elasticsearch:5.5.2 # Run the docker container 

python3
Python 3.6.12 (default, Nov 25 2020, 20:33:10) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mordecai import Geoparser
2021-03-19 20:42:19.507212: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-03-19 20:42:19.507253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>>> geo = Geoparser()
```

This is running on a SUSE Linux EC2 instance.

After trying to initialize the geoparser with geo = Geoparser(), I get the error that I posted above. I'm not quite sure about how to resolve this issue, and would appreciate any insight that you may have. I'm quite new to Docker and understand that it could have something to do with how I set up the container or networking on my host.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `localhost` in a container is the container's localhost, not the host's

Answer (score 2):

In my case the reason why such error occurred was the lack of memory allocated for the elastic search container, so it was killed and mordecai could not connect to it.

What does `docker ps -a` command return? Is your container with elastic search still running? If not, consider allocating more memory for it with docker.

Comment: Dude i have this problem and i decide to download and  install elasticsearch in my system locally instead of dockerize the elasticsearch , can you help me how to introduse the geonames_inedx to elasticsearch service? im so nub

Comment: @CryNetPlan I got it running on [google colab](https://gist.github.com/rjadr/8967effee72795dd0d9792073a9b4cd5). It will show you how to set this up in a non-dockerized way.